# Recibir Json WebService

Tags: json, vb.net, webservice, rest

Tengo que recibir una respuesta de un web service externo que contiene un json, esta respuesta tiene que llegar a mi web service, digamos `https://ejemplo/json` y como soy nuevo usando web service no sé como hacer esto, mi idea es que me llegue el json a esa dirección y guardarlo para yo manipularlo de la forma que sea necesario, pero me he perdido en este punto.

Hasta el momento he creado webservice que reciben una petición y envían una respuesta, aquí lo que trato de hacer es solamente recibir un json a mi web service y yo guardarlo, pero ya no es necesario que envíe alguna respuesta.

Comment: Te recomiendo que te crees una webapi porque es mas adecuado para trabajar con json.

Answer (score 1):

Algo así sería tu respuesta, es un ejemplo en webservices de java (WSDL)

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "recibeJson")
public boolean recibeJson(JSON dato) {
    boolean respuesta = false;
    if (dato != null) {
        respuesta = true;
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayuda a darme una idea, solo que yo uso vb.net y rest

Comment: De nada, bro! No me fije en los tag. Usa esto https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor